# Save credit card numbers between sessions

Tags: paypal

I am integrating Paypal in order to accept payments from my customers at my site and mobile app.

If a customer of mine chooses to directly pay in the paypal interface with credit card and not login with a paypal account - is there a token that paypal returns to me so that next time I can pass it back to paypal and the user will not have to re-type his credit card details?

Thanks

Nir

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't do that. Major security risk.

Comment: Not a security risk at all if done correctly.  I'm about to provide an answer with details.

Answer (score 0):

When processing authorizations or capturing payments with PayPal Express Checkout and/or Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment) you can save the transaction ID that you get back with the original transaction and then use the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) API to process future payments using the same billing details.

DoReferenceTransaction simply accepts a transaction ID (from a previous auth or sale transaction) and a new amount to be charged.

When used with Payments Pro there is nothing special you need to do with your account.  When using it with Express Checkout you need enable billing agreements / reference transactions on your account, which would be easiest by just calling PayPal and requesting it, but it doesn't cost anything extra.